# ¿Cómo veo un programa .jar que tenga System.out.println?

Tags: netbeans, jar

Para que se entienda mejor la pregunta he creado un archivo .jar con Netbeans.

Dicho archivo solo tiene códigos `System.out.println` y `Variable=X.nextInt()`

El problema es que al ejecutarlo no sale ninguna ventana con la que el usuario pueda interactuar, y se que se ejecuta el programa porque probé poner un `JOptionPane` y me lo mostro, pero no muestra lo demás... ¿Hay algún código que me muestre la consola o una ventana para que interactúe?

Comment: si es con ventanas, no es de consola... es una o la otra...

Comment: Suponiendo estés en windows, abre un `cmd` o `powershell` en la ubicación del archivo y ejecuta  `java -jar tu_programa.jar`.